# На С++ при выводе строки стринг в файл, записывает крякозябры

Tags: c++, файлы, строки, вывод

Короче, по условиям надо записывать строку в файл, если такой там нет, записать, в противном случае, ничего не делать. Вот решил, но выдает в файл крякозябры. Первая функция для определения количества строк в файле, там все окей работает)))

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int dlina(){
    char *str = new char [1024];
    int i=0;
    ifstream base("1.txt");
    while (!base.eof())
    {
        base.getline(str, 1024, '\n');
        i++;
    }
    base.close();
    delete str;
    return i;

}

int main() {
    string a;
    string b;

    ifstream fin("2.txt");

    FILE *f;
    f= fopen("2.txt", "a+");
        cin>> a;

    int len,len1;

    len1=a.length();
    len=dlina();

    bool l=false;   

    for (int i=0; i<len; i++){
        fin>>b; 

        if(a==b) l=true;
    }

    if(l==false) {
    fwrite(&a,sizeof(string),1,f);
    }
    fin.close();
    //fclose(f);
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 7):

записывать с++ строки с помощью с функций вот таким способом

```
fwrite(&a,sizeof(string),1,f);
```

нельзя. Будет писаться совсем не то, что Вы ожидаете. Даже банальная логика подсказывает, что 'sizeof(string)' не зависит от данных, которые находятся в строке.

Если Вам нужно записать именно std::string в файл таким способом, делайте так

```
fwrite(a.c_str(),(a.length()+1),1,f);
```

**P.S.**

если пишите на с++, то лучше использовать функции с++.

Comment: Отлично. Работает. Функционал на высоте, но теперь выводит не кракозябры, а китайские иероглифы

Comment: Да, это вполне возможно. Если приложение запускается с консоли, где по умолчанию кодировка 866, а файл открывается блокнотом, который скорее всего откроет это в cp1251 или utf-16, то увидеть можно все, что угодно. Даже арабскую вязь.

Comment: а можно как-то это исправить?
Я видел что надо просто не блокнот юзать а Notepad ++
с блокнотом дела не будет?

Comment: А, все , я кое как отладил. Строчек
SetConsoleCP('886');
SetConsoleOutputCP('886');
хватило чтобы убрать китайщину. Спасибо